# DevExpress ASP.NET MVC - how to handle global events?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

This is probably a fairly easy question for you ASP.NET buffs out there.  I'm playing around with the DevExpress controls for ASP.NET, using MVC.  In Razor you can set an event handler on a given DevExpress component in this way:

```
    settings.ClientSideEvents.Init = "OnInit";
```

This works well for components, but I'd like to access global events such as the "ControlsInitialized" event.  How can I do this?  Or if I'm headed down the wrong track (i.e. there's a better way to detect when controls have been initialised) please let me know.

Edit: To make my purpose more clear, I'm trying to follow this code sample, but in MVC instead of WebForms: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1081

Comment: Are you using DevExpress MVC Extensions or DevExpress for ASP.Net? The latter is really not made for MVC, so you'll probably need the MVC version and doc/example.

Comment: I'm using the MVC version.

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Comment: @Mikhail I may do just that, but I wanted to ask here first as I figured I'd get quicker answers.  I'm also just demo-ing the components at the moment, so I'm not sure what they offer non-paying customers in regards to support.

Comment: AFAIK, 30 Days Trial is for Free

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the event handler example below? MVC life cycle is more simple than ASP.NET, this is why in settings not so many event handlers.

```
settings.PreRender += (sender, args) =>
    {
        var gridView = (MVCxGridView) sender;
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I want to check to see if ALL components have loaded, not just specific ones.

Comment: What about [global.asax event](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/#.) **Application_EndRequest**?

Comment: I didn't mention this in my question (my bad), but I'm after client-side (JavaScript) events.  I want to perform an action in JavaScript once all the components have loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Use the client-side **MVCxClientGlobalEvents.ControlsInitialized** event for this purpose:

[MVCxClientGlobalEvents Members](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMVCScriptsMVCxClientGlobalEventsMembersTopicAll)

[MVCxClientGlobalEvents.ControlsInitialized](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebMVCScriptsMVCxClientGlobalEvents_ControlsInitializedtopic)

```
MVCxClientGlobalEvents.AddControlsInitializedEventHandler(
    function(s, e) {
        alert("Global Init");
    }
);
```

Comment: The problem is that object isn't available using MVC.  It's put there with WebForms using a kind of container element, which isn't present in MVC (and I'm not sure there's a way to insert it for MVC).

Comment: Which DevExpress version do you use?

Comment: DevExpress for ASP.NET but I'm using the MVC extensions.

Comment: Version 13.2 is needed: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q569129